# Can the digital edition of PS5 play discs?

Tags: ps5

I am thinking about trying to get a PS5 Digital Edition. I want to know if I could buy a game disc at GameStop and use it on my PS5 Digital Edition. I do not own any other PlayStations. Would I have to buy the regular edition to use the disc?

Answer (score 7):

The digital edition is a [Disc-Free](https://direct.playstation.com/en-us/consoles/console/playstation5-digital-edition-console.3005817) console meant only for digital downloads of games, so you will need to purchase the regular edition to use discs.